# Calculate this limit $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{(-1)^n \left(n^2 \sin (n)+2 n\right)}{{n^2}+3}$

Tags: limits

I can prove that it is less than a number eg 3/2 but cant proove that it is zero.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{(-1)^n \left(n^2 \sin (n)+2 n\right)}{{n^2}+3}$$
Any help ?

Comment: Are you sure that limit exists?

Comment: It seems it doesnt however problem asks to be found. So I guess I have to proove that it doesnt exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit doesn't exist. To see this, consider $\sin(n)$ and $-\sin(n+1)$ and $\sin(n+2)$. If $\sin(n)$ and $-\sin(n+1)$ are close, then $n$ is very close to one of just two possible values (modulo $2 \pi$). But then $\sin(n+2)$ will be far away from that value. And for large $n$, you can show that your sequence will be essentially $(-1)^n \sin(n)$. Those are the ingredients for a proof.